# Warning Undefined array key "HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm getting:

> warning Undefined array key "HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"

When I visit https:/example.com/webhook.php. That is the page where I have this code:

```
<?php

require "..../stripe-php-11.0.0/init.php";

// Your Stripe webhook endpoint secret
$webhook_secret = "whsec_...";

// Initialize Stripe with your secret API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_....");

// Get the raw request body and Stripe signature header
$payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$sig_header = $_SERVER["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"];

try {
    // Verify the signature
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload,
        $sig_header,
        $webhook_secret,
    );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Invalid signature or other error
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed":
        $session = $event->data->object;

        // Process the 'checkout.session.completed' event here
        // You can retrieve information about the completed session in $session

        // Example: Send a confirmation email to the customer
        // mail($session->customer_email, 'Order Confirmation', 'Thank you for your purchase!');
        $sessionId = $session->id;

        // Implement your logic to initiate the file download here
        http_response_code(200); // Acknowledge receipt of the event
        break;

    // Add more cases to handle other types of events as needed
    // case 'invoice.paid':
    //     // Handle invoice paid event
    //     break;

    default:
        // Unknown event type
        http_response_code(200);
        break;
}
```

I have already configured the webhook to point to the webhook URL and I checked and a successful stripe-signature was there after a successful checkout event. It's just not verifying it when I go to the site manually. I've already had events sent there I can see it on the dashboard. I obviously replaced all the `'...'` in my code with the correct stuff. How do I fix this?

Comment: Clearly the Stripe signature header is absent when you visit the webhook url using a browser. That causes the error. You could change that line of code to `$sig_header = $_SERVER["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"] ?? '';`, which removes the error, but now you will get a HTTP ERROR 400, because the code needs a valid signature to work. Is there a way to mock the signature?

Comment: Yes, I could put in data manually for the signature, I just don't know what it is. Why is the signature header absent when I visit a webhook?

Comment: The webhook response gets an error if I change the sig_header manually.

Comment: I think you have to look up [what a http header is](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers/). Clearly Stripe is sending the signature in a header. I took a look at the Stripe documentation for 5 minutes, and I see that you can [test your webhook through their Command Line Interface](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#test-webhook). Did you try that?

Comment: Yup. I tested it, I logged in, listened to my webhook url, and triggered an event. It all worked.

Comment: Webhook signatures are used to verify that Stripe (or whichever other party you're listening for webhook events from) generated a webhook request and that it didn’t come from a server acting like Stripe.

Comment: _"Why is the signature header absent when I visit a webhook?"_ - because you can't test such a webhook script by simply "visiting" it ... First of all, your "visit" is likely just a GET request (if made via the browser address bar?), whereas webhooks usually use POST. And second, such extra headers would be added to the request, when the service provider you are working with there, makes that request from their end. Your normal browser has no reason to add any such arbitrary headers to a random URL you visit.

Comment: ok thank you, but why was my post voted -1?

Comment: I just didn't understand what webhooks were but now I do, they can only be triggered on a post request, just needed someone to tell me, I hate reading. Thank you!